# Distribute 500,000 files into ten subdirectories with 50,000 files each

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have 500,000 `.abc` files. Now I want to distribute them into 10 different subdirectories that contain 50,000 of these files each.

I have tried something like

```bash
ls -1 | (cd /path/to/folder/1; split --lines=50000).
```

This is creating files such as `xaa`,`xab`,...,`xak` with names of 50,000 different `.abc` files. But they are just the names but not the files.

Comment: Do you just want to move files to different folders, but leave the files intact?   Your use of `split --lines...` suggests you want to split the individual files.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
mv `ls *.abc | head -50000` ./subfolder1/
```

Run this command 10 times with different subfolder names.

How do you want to name the 10 subfolders? Instead of running the command 10 times, a for loop could be used.

#### Explanation

- `ls *.abc | head -50000` - List first 50,000 files out of 5,00,000 .abc files
- `mv <ls part> ./subfolder1/` - Move all 50,000 listed files to directory named subfolder1

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it with a simple bash shell loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

count=0
for file in *.abc
do
  dir=$(( count / 50000 ))
  (( count++ ))
  [ ! -d "$dir" ] && mkdir "$dir"
  echo mv -- "$file" "$dir"/
done
```

This hardcodes a number of files to move to each directory; the directories are named incrementally starting from zero.

In a much shorter example (moving only 20 files 10 at a time into 2 directories), the output is:

```
mv -- 01.abc 0/
mv -- 02.abc 0/
mv -- 03.abc 0/
mv -- 04.abc 0/
mv -- 05.abc 0/
mv -- 06.abc 0/
mv -- 07.abc 0/
mv -- 08.abc 0/
mv -- 09.abc 0/
mv -- 10.abc 0/
mv -- 11.abc 1/
mv -- 12.abc 1/
mv -- 13.abc 1/
mv -- 14.abc 1/
mv -- 15.abc 1/
mv -- 16.abc 1/
mv -- 17.abc 1/
mv -- 18.abc 1/
mv -- 19.abc 1/
mv -- 20.abc 1/
```

Remove the `echo` if the results look correct for you.